# PETSC Memory Leak

Tags: petsc

I tried to use PETSC direct solver (SUPER LU) to solve the system of equations.
After a long time effort, the code is working properly and gives some good results. The only issue that came up recently is a bout memory leakage.
I found that after iterations RES memory is increasing which leads to the server crash.
I tried bunch of cures which I found on the web, but none of them worked.
I am using MatDestroy and VecDestroy at the end of PETSC part in the code to free all the allocated memories. This is not helpful.
I also tried iterative solvers like Richardson and other direct solver like spooles and the same problem occurred.
I would appreciate if you could help me in this regard.

Comment: This seems like a question that might be better suited to the PETSc mailing list.

Comment: @Foad I replied to your mail on the petsc-users mailing list, but your email address rejected my mail.  You can read it here: http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-users/2013-April/017124.html

Comment: Are you sure that the memory leak is caused by the library and not in your code? Perhaps allocating memory for a pointer which is used reallocated internally? Valgrind might help.